# Dispose of Get-SPOSite in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

In Powershell for sharepoint server, we use dispose() for disposing SPSite objects, do we do the same in sharepoint online management shell? or it's not needed?

Comment: No you don't have to dispose

Comment: No disposal needed. I guess the infrastructure team for SPO wouldn't sleep to well at nights otherwise. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't have to dispose, this is handled on the SharePoint servers for you